# painting QLinearGradient in QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, gradient, qgraphicsitem

I originally implement my graph by drawing all the content in the `QWidget::paintEvent()`. I have a function `drawHeatMapLegend()` to draw a box with QLinearGradient to represent a heat-map for my graph as legend.

**Original implementation**

```
widMapGraph::widMapGraph(QWidget parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {
    gradient_.setCoordinateMode(QGradient::ObjectBoundingMode);
    gradient_.setColorAt(0.0, Qt::green);
    gradient_.setColorAt(0.3, Qt::yellow);
    gradient_.setColorAt(0.6, Qt::red);
}

void widMapGraph::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    drawHeatMapLegend(&painter);
}

void widMapGraph::drawHeatMapLegend(QPainter* painter) {
    QRect legendBox(30, 70, 25, 100);
    int left = legendBox.left() + legendBox.width() + 10;
    painter->save();
    painter->setPen(QPen());
    painter->setBrush(gradient_);
    painter->drawRect(legendBox);
    painter->drawText(left, legendBox.top(), "0.00%");
    painter->drawText(left, legendBox.top() + legendBox.height() / 2, "50.00%");
    painter->drawText(left, legendBox.top() + legendBox.height(), "100.00%");
    painter->restore();
} // end: (widMapGraph::drawHeatMapLegend)
```

Now, I try to use QGraphicScene/QGraphicsView framework for my graph and I implement a subclass of QGraphicsRectItem for my map legend.

**Class definition**

```
class MapLegend : public QObject, public QGraphicsRectItem {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MapLegend(QGraphicsItem *parent = 0);
    void paint (QPainter *painter,
                const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                QWidget *widget);
    QLinearGradient gradient_;
    /* other members */
}
```

**Class implementation**

```
MapLegend::MapLegend(QGraphicsItem *parent) : QGraphicsRectItem(parent) {
    setRect(30, 70, 25, 100);
    gradient_.setCoordinateMode(QGradient::ObjectBoundingMode);
    gradient_.setColorAt(0.0, Qt::green);
    gradient_.setColorAt(0.3, Qt::yellow);
    gradient_.setColorAt(0.6, Qt::red);
} // end_ctor(MapLegend)

void MapLegend::paint(QPainter *painter,
                      const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                      QWidget *widget)
{
    Q_UNUSED(option);
    Q_UNUSED(widget);
    int left = rect().left() + rect().width() + 10;
    painter->setPen(QPen());
    painter->setBrush(gradient_);
    painter->drawRect(rect());
    painter->drawText(left, rect().top(), "0.00%");
    painter->drawText(left, rect().top() + rect().height() / 2, "50.00%");
    painter->drawText(left, rect().top() + rect().height(), "100.00%");
} // end: MapLegend::paint()

void My2ndGraph::task() {
    myView->scene()->clear();
    myView->scene()->addItem(myLegend); // myLegend is a class variable as MapLegend
    update();
}
```

*Result* The orange box shows two examples using 2nd implementation

[image: Result]

**Question** The original implementation correctly show a gradient 'vertically' along the box, but the new implementation draw the gradient diagonally. Is there anything I missed that why the two implementations behavior dis-agree? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't set the start and stop end points of the gradient, so it defaults to using the top left and bottom right corners:

> QLinearGradient::QLinearGradient() Constructs a default linear
>   gradient with interpolation area between (0, 0) and (1, 1).

and:

> QGradient::ObjectBoundingMode: In this mode the gradient coordinates
>   are relative to the bounding rectangle of the object being drawn, with
>   (0,0) in the top left corner, and (1,1) in the bottom right corner of
>   the object's bounding rectangle.

So you will need to manually tell it the gradient direction, like this:

```
gradient_.setStart( 0.0, 0.0 );
gradient_.setFinalStop( 0.0, 1.0 );
```

Or when initialised:

```
MapLegend::MapLegend(QGraphicsItem *parent) : QGraphicsRectItem(parent),
    gradient_( QLinearGradient( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ) ) { ... }
```

As for why it worked inside a `QWidget`?  I have no idea, it shouldn't have!